# MYSQL Database PIVOT and wants in specific format

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have below table and its data in mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `pointhistory` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `channelid` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `deviceid` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `pointid` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `pointvalue` double NOT NULL,
  `pointtime` datetime NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_HP_POINTID` (`pointid`),
  KEY `IDX_HP_DEVICEID` (`deviceid`),
  KEY `IDX_HP_POINTTIME` (`pointtime`),
  KEY `IDX_HP_CHANNELID` (`channelid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=108947 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is a set of sample data available on: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c0f6c

```
ID      CHANNELID DEVICEID  POINTID POINTVALUE  POINTTIME
108947  13010004    2-0     3-11    123.45  October, 01 2014 02:22:32+0000
108948  13010004    2-0     3-1     432.41  October, 01 2014 02:22:32+0000
108949  13010002    2-0     3-11    12.4    October, 01 2014 02:28:32+0000
108950  13010002    2-0     3-1     43.41   October, 01 2014 02:28:32+0000
108951  130100040   2-0     3-11    23.45   October, 01 2014 03:45:34+0000
108952  130100040   2-0     3-1     43222.45    October, 01 2014 03:45:34+0000
108953  130100040   2-0     3-11    23.45   October, 01 2014 05:25:32+0000
108954  130100040   2-0     3-1     43212.45    October, 01 2014 05:25:32+0000
108955  13010004    2-0     3-11    123.45  October, 01 2014 05:27:32+0000
108956  13010004    2-0     3-1     432.41  October, 01 2014 05:27:32+0000
108957  13010002    2-0     3-11    12.4    October, 01 2014 05:27:32+0000
108958  13010002    2-0     3-1     434.41  October, 01 2014 05:27:32+0000
108959  130100040   2-0     3-11    23.45   October, 01 2014 08:45:34+0000
108960  130100040   2-0     3-1     43212.45    October, 01 2014 08:45:34+0000
```

and i want this table data to see in below format

```
channelid     deviceid pointtime                pointid3_1  pointid3_11 
13010004      2-0      2014-10-01 02:22:32      432.41      123.45
13010002      2-0      2014-10-01 02:28:32      43.41       12.4
130100040     2-0      2014-10-01 03:45:34      43222.45    23.45       
130100040     2-0      2014-10-01 05:25:32      43212.45    23.45
13010004      2-0      2014-10-01 05:27:32      432.41      123.45
13010002      2-0      2014-10-01 05:27:32      434.41      12.4
130100040     2-0      2014-10-01 08:45:34      43212.45    23.45
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make it using GROUP BY in MYSQL, Hope this helps!

```
SELECT
    channelid,
    deviceid,
    pointtime,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(pointvalue ORDER BY pointid ASC SEPARATOR '^'),'^',1) AS pointid3_1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(pointvalue ORDER BY pointid ASC SEPARATOR '^'),'^',-1) AS pointid3_11
FROM
    Think.pointhistory
GROUP BY
    pointtime,
    channelid;
```